# Django template add class to link

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to add another class to my div when this condition execute.

```
{% for k in all_conversations %}
  <div {% if k.id == current_id %}class="shape"{% else %}class="emptyshape"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'chatapp:chat' k.id %}">{{k.seller}}</a></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Everything is correct but it doesn't add class name and always executes else condition. current id in this situation is 212 but it doesn't work 
if i write in this way

```
<div {% if k.id == 212 %}class="shape"{% else %}class="emptyshape"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'chatapp:chat' k.id %}">{{k.seller}}</a></div>
```

it works perfectly fine.

my views.py

```
def chatpage(request, id):
    current_id = id
    all_conversations = Conversation.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'templates/chat/chatexc.html',
              {'all_conversations': all_conversations,
               'messages': messages,
               'current_id': current_id,})
```

Comment: What is `k`, `k.id` and `current_id`?

Comment: k.id is 212 and 213 in my for loop, and current_id is 212. in every situation current_id matches with on of the k.id.

Comment: Are you sure? have you checked? It looks likely that `current_id` isn't set, please try to make an [mcve]

Comment: @Sayse yes i'm sure i checked it

Comment: @Sayse i added my view

Comment: current_id is a _string_ "212", but id is the int 212. Not the same thing... pass int(current_id) to the template instead.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Thank you, it works..